# OP AMP DESIGN - The first bit is fine

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, power-engineering

[image: Hello guys, can you help me with the second bit of the question? I found the first two answers ... I proved that vo = 2(v2-v1) and r = 800ohms ... but with for the second bit I got stuck in an expression with 2V2 an 1V1...]

Hello guys, can you help me with the second bit of the question? I found the first two answers ... I proved that vo = 2(v2-v1) and r = 800ohms ... but with for the second bit I got stuck in an expression with 2V2 an 1V1...

Comment: Be specific. Where did you get stuck? What part of the second bit? How far did you get before you realized you were stuck? Where's your work for the second bit so far?

Comment: I got stuck in the second design... I know that V+  =  V_ ...right?
and (V1 - V_)/R1 = (V_ - Vo)/R2 ....right ?
If V+ = V_ = V2R4/(R3+R4) ....

I got there...When I put the equations together... I do not know how can I prove that Vo = 2(V2-V1)... neither get values for Resistances

Comment: The trick is that you need to pick a resistor value and calculate the rest based on that resistance. Just remember that the resistors need to be 1/2 watt, so (V^2)/R (the voltage drop across the resistor squared and divided by the resistance you choose) cannot exceed 0.5W.

Comment: But should I use the same value for R1,R2,R3 and R4 ? like 0.5K ohms ... because if I consider 20V as the ddp... it wont exceed 0.5 w

Comment: I believe R1-R4 are all independent resistors, so each of them may have whatever value provides the correct output from the op-amp. They do not have to have the same value.

Comment: I am trying here to solve, but did not have success ... thanks for helping me out, if you have any more clues, please send me

Comment: Start by showing us your work, and we'll point to where you went wrong.

Comment: Imagine I'd approach you saying the "spaghetti - the water is already boiling" - would you know what my question is? No you would not.  Please clarify the title and amend the details to your question you added in the comments (use the "edit" link below your post).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your question with decent explanation:
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html
(There is one error at the final expression though, it should be Vout = R3/R1*(V2-V1) not Vout = -R3/R1*(V2-V1))

So in your case you should choose R1=R3 and R2=R4. And the output expression for you is: Vout = R2/R1*(V2-V1). So choosing the values of R2 and R4 twice as large as the values of R1 and R3 would be sufficient. For power consideration, large enough values like 2k and 1k ohms would be ok.